# I want to grab the query params from the url bar and make an API requrest depending on the query params

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, web-frontend

I am trying to copy the search functionality of anilist.co .
When I try to grab the query params using useSearchparams() the useEffect runs infinitely,
Even adding the qp variable in the dependency array is not fixing it.

Here is the code snippet of what I am doing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGrwo.png)

// this should make sure useEffect runs only when query params are changed

> The qp variable should have stopped the useEffect from working infinitely, but it doesnt seem to work. Also maybe I could have a better approach to emulate the anilist.co search functionality

Comment: Saying "search functionality of anilist.co" tells me nothing. Do not post code as images, post it as text. Please make sure your question contains a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useEffect is running infinitely because the dependency parameter and state that you are updated (pq) in useEffect are the same(It keeps updating that's why useEffect is running again and again). Try using the code snippet, mentioned below.

Hope this helps you.

```js
function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}

const query = useQuery();
 const productId = query.get("productId");
  
  
  const fetchData= async() =>{
    await axios.get("http://localhost:3500/api/anime",{params:productId}).then((res)=>{
      setAllAnime(res.data);
    })
    
    }
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(productId)
    {
      fetchData()
    }
    },[productId])
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked out exactly as I had planned. One question thoug, Why does my qp parameter change value? I am explicitly telling it to change inside the callback of useEffect using setQp

Comment: Because in dependency array of useEffect you are passing qp. Each time you set value of qp that useEffect is called and you are setting value of qp in useEffect.